# Android Enthusiast or Super User: Android device to boot an ISO file on Windows suite

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I have a question regarding to boot an ISO file from an Android device. The boot is to be done for Windows 8.1. So is this question suited here or on Super User?

Comment: To clarify, you want to have Android hardware running Windows RT?  That sounds like more of a SU question but I'm not sure if they would accept it.  I am also fairly confident you won't get an answer since that is no easy task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this one, I still think that your question is on-topic on here.

From [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),

> If your question generally covers...
>
> - **Using your Android device**
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device

Yes, the question is about using Android device to boot an ISO file. Whether if it's possible or not, we don't know yet, but that doesn't make the question off-topic. I also don't see any off-topic reasons that can be applied to your question.

> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)
> - Marketing your Android app or doing market research
> - Issues with the Google Play Store (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher
> - Recommendations, like "Which phone is better?" or "Can you suggest an app that does X?"
> - Shopping advice and suggestions, including what device to buy or where to buy it
> - Speculative questions, like "When will X be available in my country?" or "Why does Company X do this?"
> - Legal questions, such as "Will X void my warranty?"
> - Android-independent questions, such as "Does Carrier X have prepaid plans?"

---

On the other hand, [using mobile-related device is off-topic on Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

> and it is not about …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - *electronic devices, media players, cell phones or **smart phones**, except insofar as they interface with your computer,*
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,

As I see, your question is not about using PC to interact with Android device, making it off-topic there.